# I'm trying to connect to a big query database that I have created and insert form data based on user input

Tags: php, html, google-bigquery

I have been running my code and getting without errors and getting the "connected to big query" and "Data has been successfully inserted into the Survey table." , but when I query my database it returns no records. I've been troubleshooting for a couple days now and am not really sure what the problem is.

```
    `use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
    use Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException;
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    #Connect to config file and declare variables
    require 'config.php';       
    $ProjectID = PROJECT_ID;
    $Dataset = DATASET_ID;
    $Table =TABLE_ID;
    $json = JSON_KEY_FILE;


    try {
        $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
            'projectId' => $ProjectID,
            'keyFilePath' => $json
        ]);
        
        $surveyTable = $bigQuery->dataset($Dataset)->table($Table);

        $insertData = [[
            'data' => [
            'key' => uniqid(),
            'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
            'gender' => $_POST['gender'],
            'address1' => $_POST['address1'],
            'email' => $_POST['email']
            ]
            ]];
        $surveyTable->insertRows($insertData);
        echo "Connected to BigQuery!";
        echo "<p>Data has been successfully inserted into the $Table table.</p>";

        var_dump($insertData);
    
    
     } catch (ServiceException $ex) {
     echo "<p>Error: Data was not inserted into the $Table table.</p>";
     printf('Error: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getMessage());
     printf('Error code: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getCode());
     printf('Error status: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getStatus());
     printf('Error details: %s' . PHP_EOL, json_encode($ex->getDetails()));
     }`
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to debug this is check the bigquery information schema and look for jobs. For the request you are generating from your code, a new job will be created, check if its getting created here. if its not, then the issue is your request not hitting the bigquery, but if you see job entry, then you can also check any issues there.

hope this helps

SELECT
*
FROM
`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE
job_type = 'LOAD';

Comment: So it looks like it's not creating a job, but I do still believe it is connected to the right database and project because when i change any of the values in my 'config.php' file it immediately throws an error. I also have it connected to a service account that i created which has ownership of the project.

Comment: Okay noted, It is little difficult to comment without the config.php file. having said, your next step to debug is 1) cloud logging 2) in cloud shell, using bq cli initiate the same insert table command that your program is running. finally, i am assuming there is input data replaced in those substitution variables :-)